# search engine and pagination

Tags: php

Hello Friends I want to know how to add pagination in search engine. I have tried so many times to add pagination in search engine but every time i was fail. Is there anybody who modify my following code to add pagination:

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'func.inc.php'; ?>

<html>

<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>

<body>

<h2> Search </h2>

<form action="" method="POST">
        <p>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="keywords" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['keywords'])) {
$suffix = "";
$keywords = mysql_real_escape_string (htmlentities (trim($_POST['keywords'])));

    $errors = array();

    if (empty($keywords)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a search term';
    } else if (strlen($keywords)<3) {
        $errors[] = 'Your search term must be three or more character';
    } else if (search_results($keywords) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Your search for ' .$keywords. ' returned no result';
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $results = search_results ($keywords);
        $results_num = count ($results);

        $suffix = ($results_num !=1) ? 's' : '';

        echo '<p> Your search for <strong>', $keywords,'</strong> returned <strong>',$results_num,'</strong> result',$suffix,'</p>';
        foreach($results as $result) {
            echo '<p><strong><a href="',$result['url'],'">', $result['title'],'</a></strong> <br>', $result['description'],'...<br>', $result['url'],'</p>';
            }

    } else {
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error, '</br>';
    }
        }

    }

?>


</body>
</html>
```

**func.inc.php**

```
   <?php 
include 'db.inc.php'; 

function search_results($keywords) {
    $returned_results = array();
    $where ="";

    $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
    $total_keywords = count($keywords);

    foreach ($keywords as $key=>$keyword) {
      $where .="`keywords` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
      if ($key != ($total_keywords - 1)) {
        $where .= "AND";
        }
    }

    $results = "SELECT `title`, LEFT(`description`, 70) as `description`, `url` FROM `articles` WHERE $where";
    $results_num = ($results = mysql_query($results)) ? mysql_num_rows($results): 0;

    if ($results_num === 0) {
    return false;
    } else {

    while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $returned_results[] = array(
                    'title' => $results_row['title'],
                    'description' => $results_row['title'],
                    'url' => $results_row['url']


        );
    }

    return $returned_results;
}
}

?>
```

And i have one more question  to make a close button at the top of the Div for closing itself.

Answer (score 3):

I'd amend the function signature to include page number and number of results per page:

```
function search_results($keywords,$pagenum,$resultsperpage) {
```

and then amend the SQL to pull out only the results for the page in question:

```
$startresult=($pagenum-1)*$resultsperpage;
$results = "SELECT `title`, LEFT(`description`, 70) as `description`, `url` FROM `articles` WHERE $where LIMIT $startresult,$resultsperpage";
```

(assuming you'd be numbering you pages starting from `1`)

Then all you'd need is a list of links to let the users select their page. I normally use a `GET` variable for this (`searchpage.php?p=1` maybe), so you'd have to sanitize that as you have done with your search terms.

Answer (score 0):

Please not remember Likes

```
  <?php 
    include 'func.php'; 
    include 'config.inc.php'; 
    ?>

    <form action="" method="POST">
            <p>
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="keywords" > <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
    </form>
    <?php

    $suffix = "";
    $v='';

    if(isset($_POST['keywords'])){$v=$_POST['keywords'];}
    else{
         if(isset($_GET['q'])){$v=$_GET['q'];}

        }

    $keywords = mysql_real_escape_string (htmlentities (trim($v)));

        $errors = array();

        if (empty($keywords)) {
            $errors[] = 'Please enter a search term';
        } else if (strlen($keywords)<3) {
            $errors[] = 'Your search term must be three or more character';
        } else if (search_results($keywords) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Your search for ' .$keywords. ' returned no result';
        }
        if (!($errors)) {
            $results = search_results($keywords);

            $results_num = count ($results);
            $suffix = ($results_num !=1) ? 's' : '';

            echo '<p> Your search for <strong>', $keywords,'</strong> returned <strong>',$results_num,'</strong> result',$nom,'</p>';

            foreach($results as $result) {

                echo '<p><strong><a href="',$result['message'],'">', $result['name'],'</a></strong> <br>', $result['id'],'...<br>', $result['message'],'</p>';

                   }

    if($pages>=1 && $page<=$pages){
    for($x=1;$x<=$pages;$x++){

    echo ($x==$page) ? '<strong><a href="?page='.$x.'&q='.$v.'" >'.$x.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href="?page='.$x.'&q='.$v.'" >'.$x.'</a> ';
     }
    }
         } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error, '</br>';
        }
            }   
    ?>
```

func.in.php

```
    <?php 

    function search_results($keywords) {
    global $page,$start,$pages_query,$per_page,$pages,$returned_results,$total_keywords,$nom;
        $returned_results = array();
        $where ="";

        $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
        $total_keywords = count($keywords);

        foreach ($keywords as $key=>$keyword) {
          $where .="`message` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
          if ($key != ($total_keywords - 1)) {
            $where .= "AND";
            }
        }


    $per_page=6;
    $pages_query = mysql_query(' SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `paginate` ') or die(mysql_error());

    //$pages=ceil(mysql_result($pages_query,0) / $per_page);

        $resultt = "SELECT * FROM paginate WHERE $where  ";
        $queryt =mysql_query($resultt) ;
        $nom=mysql_num_rows($queryt);
    $pages=ceil($nom / $per_page);    


    $page= (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] :1;

    $start=($page - 1) * $per_page;


        $results = "SELECT * FROM paginate WHERE $where LIMIT $start,$per_page ";
        $results_num = ($results = mysql_query($results)) ? mysql_num_rows($results): 0;



        if ($results_num === 0) {
        return false;
        } else {

        while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
            $returned_results[] = array(
                        'id' => $results_row['id'],
                        'name' => $results_row['name'],
                        'message' => $results_row['message']


            );
        }

        return $returned_results;
    }
    }

    ?>
```